# How to Convert [object object] to File in javascript/Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have multiple files when I add new file it stores as a file type but existing file type comes as a [object object], I want to convert [object object] type into file type. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Do you not just want to creat a '*.json' file?

Comment: it is file upload feature, when i add new file it is working but existing file is taking [object object]

Comment: Please provide the snippet of the code to get more context.

Comment: it is coming something like this  in response header
    
data: { 
 otherNotes:null

 officeDetails:null
 
 Files:
 
 [object Object]
 
 Files:
 
 [object Object]
 
 Files:
 
 [object Object]
 
 Files:
 
 [object Object]
 
 Files:
 
 [object Object]
 
 
 Files:
 
 [object Object]
 
 
 Files:
 
 [object Object]
 
 
 Files:
 
 (binary)
 
}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.